# Retriving JSON values from asp.net response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery

I'm working on a small project. Mostly to gain some understanding because I am a complete web noob. Which may or may not be apparent in the following question(s).

My end result is fetching a bunch of values from a database. Putting them into a JSON object and then using some jQuery/JavaScript to work with the data. I've been doing a ton of reading, been through tons of posts on here but I can't find something as it relates to my problem.

I'm working in VS2010 C#. I'm bound by IE7 on the client side, but I can test with Firefox. I'm also working on `localHost` for now.

My JavaScript is as follows.

```
function plotMarkers() {
var pathStart = new String(window.location);
var newPath = pathStart.replace("Default.aspx", "getMarkers.aspx");
alert(newPath);
$("#statusDiv").html('<a href="' + newPath + '">JSON Data</a>');

$.getJSON(newPath, function (data) {

    alert("Loading JSON");
    $.each(data, function (index, elem) {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(elem.lat, elem.lng);
        var marker = new gogle.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: elem.title
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    });

}, function () { alert("loaded") });}
```

I don't get any Javascript errors in Firefox, but I do in IE7. The `alert("Loading JSON")` never fires anywhere. I've never seen it.

My getMarkers.aspx code

```
public partial class getMarkers : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<marker> markerList = new List<marker>();
        markerList.Add(new marker(-34.397, 150.644, "Test"));
        markerList.Add(new marker(-50, 150.644, "Test2"));

        string sJSON = jsonSer.Serialize(markerList);
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write(sJSON);
    }
}
```

I can click the link in "statusDiv" and it takes me to the aspx page. I get an error in IE7 but it works fine in Firefox. The JSON that is parsed back to me in those pages is correct. I copy and pasted the response in another function and the plotter put the two pins on my map.

1. The code does not seem to enter the `$.getJSON` function.
2. There is a problem with IE7 (or a problem in general) with how my `getMarkers.aspx` is set up. Googled some tutorials and this is where I ended up. I might be completely wrong in my approach. Or I missed something I was supposed to do. I can't seem to find that specific tutorial, it must have been closed on accident amidst my furious 2 day and counting Google adventure.

Firefox `getMarkers.aspx` displays the JSON as the first line followed by the html. Just plaintext in the browser.

IE7 displays an XML error and tells me the JSON string isn't allowed at the top level of the document. I did read some articles about IE7 always trying to parse XML with an elaborate workaround. Which I can't do, because I don't know how many clients will be using it. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

If anyone could point me in the direction I need to go I would greatly appreciate it. Hopefully my post isn't too convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a Response.End() at the end of your page load method, so that the rest of the web page isn't rendered after your JSON.

Comment: Better still use an HttpHandler as it's much lighter weight.

Comment: Or WebAPI if using .NET 4.5 :)

Comment: That was it. I still get a JS error in IE but it runs and plots. Makes sense. I'm assuming it was attempting parse out all the HTML as JSON and then it just failed. (Am I close?) Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you have any code in your .aspx file before you added Response.End()? If so that might be what IE didn't like

Comment: I had the test data for the serialization in there. The response was dumping the html out and I think jQuery was trying to parse it and failing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, for starters, that you need the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library to handle the issues with IE7.

As for firing your function - I can't see anywhere where plotMarkers() is actually called, it's only defined?

Comment: It's called from `$(document).ready` the code that puts the url in statusDiv is working so I know it makes it that far.

Comment: Ahh, okay, that's fine. Can you install Firebug for Firefox and see if any result is coming back from your .aspx page when it's called from your client-side call, or if it's 404ing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display markers on a map in an existing page when the #statusDiv link is clicked ?
If so, you're doing it wrong : dont put a link in #statusDiv, just make sure the getJSON function is called when you click on it. try this :

```
function plotMarkers() {
    var pathStart = new String(window.location);
    var newPath = pathStart.replace("Default.aspx", "getMarkers.aspx");
    alert(newPath);
    $("#statusDiv").text('JSON Data');
    $("#statusDiv").on('click',function(){

        $.getJSON(newPath, function (data) {

        alert("Loading JSON");
        $.each(data, function (index, elem) {

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(elem.lat, elem.lng);
            var marker = new gogle.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                 title: elem.title
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        });

    }, function () { alert("loaded") });
});
}
```

Comment: No, the plotting happens when the page loads. I didn't include that code because it works. I just put it in this function so it was modular. All of the alerts and div updates were for debugging.